Getting wrong number of response render on intial rendering
I have written a Reactjs code . Here the first api is rendering the list of job ids . and in next api each job id is rendering the job detail of that id . here is the example .
api 1 - https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/jobstories.json 
o/p 1 - [35908337, 35904973, 35900922, 35893439, 35890114, 35880345, ...]
api 2 - https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/35908337.json
o/p 2 - {
  "by": "jamilbk",
  "id": 35908337,
  "score": 1,
  "time": 1683838872,
  "title": "Firezone (YC W22) is hiring Elixir and Rust engineers",
  "type": "job",
  "url": "https://www.ycombinator.com/companies/firezone/jobs"
} 

Now I have wriiten a react js code for it to achieve the same .

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [jobId, setJobId] = useState([]);
  const [jobData, setJobData] = useState([]);
  const [pages, SetPages] = useState(0);
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true);   
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const No_Of_Pages = 6;
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchJobId();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (jobId.length > 0) fetchJobData();
  }, [pages, jobId]);

  const fetchJobId = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/jobstories.json"
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    setJobId(data);
  };

  const fetchJobData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const JobrangeId = jobId.slice(
      pages * No_Of_Pages,
      (pages + 1) * No_Of_Pages
    ); // 0-6 , 6-12 , 12-18 ...
    const JobDataPromise = JobrangeId.map(async (id) => {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${id}.json`
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      return data;
    });
    const jobInfo = await Promise.all(JobDataPromise);
    setJobData((prevjob) => [...prevjob, ...jobInfo]);
    setHasMore((pages + 1) * No_Of_Pages < jobData.length);
    setLoading(false);
  };
  return (
    <div className="">
      <div className="h-[500px] w-[100%]  relative p-4 bg-gray-50 overflow-y-scroll">
        <div className="flex flex-col w-[100%] h-[100%] items-center ">
          <p className="text-orange-400 font-bold text-2xl">
            {" "}
            Hacker News Jobs Board
          </p>
          {jobData.length > 0
            ? jobData.map((ele, index) => (
                <div
                  className="w-5/6 h-16 border-[1.5px] border-gray-300 m-3 p-1.5 bg-white"
                  key={index}
                >
                  <div className="flex flex-col ">
                    <div>
                      <p className="font-bold text-black text-xl">
                        {ele?.title}
                      </p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="flex justify-start gap-2">
                      <p className="font-normal text-base">By {ele?.by}</p>
                      <p>-</p>
                      <p>{ele?.time}</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))
            : null}
          <div className="w-5/6 flex justify-start">
            <button
              className="p-3 bg-orange-400 text-white rounded-md"
              onClick={() => SetPages(pages + 1)}
              disabled={hasMore}
            >
              {loading ? "Loading..." : "Load more"}
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


The error I am getting here is on intial render it is rendering 12 job details instead of 6 . In 12 the last 6 are the same to that of first 6 . in subsequent rendering on click of load more button it is rendering correctly . Why it is happening like that ? What is wrong in my code ? Thanks in advance .

you try to delete StrictMode

it is working correctly when I have removed React.strictMode . but why it is not working in React.StrictMode?

it is just a mechanism to detect errors and help detect application problems of react, it has no problem. When going to production, there will be no strictmode anymore. If you find that there are too many re-render logs during development, you can install the React Developer Tools extension, press f12, there will be a tag called profiler, you can hide the log from strictmode.

I suggest having a read of this part in the docs: https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#fetching-data, it calls out how to handle this type of thing.

This happens when you have your App code closed inside the Strict Mode. If you're using vite to build your react app, this would possibly be in your main.jsx like
<React.StrictMode>
    <App />
</React.StrictMode>

You need to remove the <React.StrictMode> and </React.StrictMode> lines. The API wont be called twice on the first render now.
Moreover, this happens only during local development. Once you have your code deployed, the API wont be called twice in the production environment even if you dont remove the StrictMode.
